# Search Results web part populating without any search terms being entered into Search Box web part

Tags: search, search-results, search-results-webpart

I am having the same issue as the user in this link:  [Search results webpart displaying items without search box query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132257/search-results-webpart-displaying-items-without-search-box-query)

I have a Search Box web part + Search Results web part (and my result source is a wiki enterprise page).  Before any terms are entered in Search Box, all possible results are displaying in the Search Results.  Again, this is before any search is actually performed. All answers in linked article have been attempted, and all have failed.

Is there a way to have Search Result web part not display any results until a search has actually been performed by the user?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, I have seen answers in these following articles ( http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187573/avoid-default-results-in-search-result-web-part & https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/sharepoint2013-avoid-default-results-in-search-result-and-content-search-web-part-with-search-box/ ).  While the answers in these articles do prevent results from populating before a search term is entered, I need a solution that does not display the 'Nothing here matches your search' default message.

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting all results to display is a matter of adjusting your Search Results Query is the difference between:

Only show results with an entered search term (no results with no search term)

```
{searchboxquery}
```

Show all results unless a search term, then show that

```
* {searchboxquery}
```

What you want, however, is to not show the Search Results web part at all until a search has been made. SharePoint accomplishes this in the search center by providing a page with only the Search Box web part configured to show its results on a results page. The results page has both the Search Box and Search Results (among others) web parts on it.

You are building a results page and not wanting results. Instead, you should build a search page that displays its results on a separate page.